# Враги должны воспринимать друг друга, как препятствие. Unity2D, C#

Tags: c#, unity3d, искусственный-интеллект

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы враги обходили друг друга, потому что они просто проходят сквозь, а когда гонятся за игроком и вовсе сливаются воедино (Они могут летать по всем 2 векторам), как решить эту проблему?

Я добавлял им коллайдеры, но тогда они не могли пройти в узкий проход. Я делал их коллайдер препятствием (в настройках БЕСПЛАТНОЙ версий ассета Astar Pathfinding Project) в их ИИ, но тогда они пытались уйти от самих себя, думая, что в них есть препятствия и просто суетились.

Может вы знаете какой - нибудь бесплатный ассет или видео, где показывается, как решить эту проблему, статью?

Comment: Согласен, но почему его ещё не разблокировали? Или это ещё рассматривается?

Comment: А что вы в нем исправили? Вопрос должен подразумевать конкретный вопрос, а не "как реализовать фичу X?".

Comment: Я попросил скинуть какой - нибудь сайт, где есть ответ, как это реализовать. Также, вы указали, что ответ слишком общий. Почитав в справке и узнав, что наверняка где - то есть материал (статья или видео, книга, в конце концов), я решил, что логичнее спросить ссылку, ибо я думаю, что кто - то явно сталкивался с моей проблемой и как - то решил это, найдя ресурс в интернете

Comment: Данный сайт предназначен для вопросов и ответов, ответы в виде ссылки тут не приветствуются по одной просто причине: ссылка может рано или поздно умереть. Да и какой смысл от ответа, который является ссылкой на другой ответ, если эту ссылку можно откопать в гугле?

Comment: Более того, ваш вопрос не несете никакой пользы, вы хотите получить платный функционал в бесплатной версии **определенного** плагина, с чем вряд ли кто-либо когда-либо еще столкнется. Учитывая написанное выше, можно сделать вывод, что этот вопрос и ответ не будут нести вообще никакого смысла для сообщества.

Comment: Ваши аргументы звучат логично. Пожалуй, вы правы